# Itemid = 435 sendo adicionado no final do link da página

Tags: php, cms

Eu estou usando um modelo de galeria de fotos. Ao clicar em uma foto na lista que é exibida, abre uma nova página perfeitamente bem. Mas não cria uma nova página, adiciona à página atual.

Tenho notado que a URL incorporou `Itemid = 435` no final de cada link. Se eu remover este elemento a página funciona bem novamente. Alguma ideia de como impedir que isso aconteça?

O código é este:

```
**<form action="index.php?option=com_igallery&amp;view=category&amp;id=<?php echo $this->category->id; ?>&amp;Itemid=<?php echo $this->Itemid; ?>" method="post" name="ig_menu_pagination">**

<?php 
if(count($this->categoryChildren) != 0)
{
    ?>
    <div id="cat_child_wrapper<?php echo $this->uniqueid; ?>" class="cat_child_wrapper">
    <?php
    $counter = 0;
    $columns = $this->profile->columns == 0 ? count($this->categoryChildren) : $this->profile->columns;

    while( $counter < count($this->categoryChildren) )
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$columns; $i++)
        {
            if( isset($this->categoryChildren[$counter]) )
            {
                **$row = $this->categoryChildren[$counter];
                $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_igallery&amp;view=category&amp;igid='.$row->id.'&amp;Itemid='.$this->Itemid);
                ?>**

                <div class="cat_child" style="width: <?php echo $row->menu_max_width; ?>px;">
                    **<h3 class="cat_child_h3">
                        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="cat_child_a">
                            <?php echo $row->name; ?>
                        </a>
                    </h3>**
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja que o link abra em uma nova aba/janela substitua:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="cat_child_a">
```

por

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_BLANK" class="cat_child_a">
```

Comment: eu quero remover o Itemid = 435 que aparece no final do link.

Comment: Então altere "$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_igallery&amp;view=category&amp;igid='.$row->id.'&amp;Itemid='.$this->Itemid);" para "$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_igallery&amp;view=category&amp;igid='.$row->id);"

Answer (score 0):

Assim esse itemid está ali por algum motivo, porém segue abaixo removido.

```
$linkItemid = igUtilityHelper::getItemid($row->gallery_id);
$photoList[$i]->link = 'index.php?option=com_igallery&view=category&igid='.$row->gallery_id.'&image='.$row->ordering;
$photoList[$i]->target_blank = 0;
```

Comment: desculpa mais não deu certo

Comment: esse código que te enviei não deu certo.

Comment: eu editei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você não quer que o link abra com o parâmetro **Itemid**, pra isso remova essa parâmetro do seu `$link`.

```
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_igallery&amp;view=category&amp;igid='.$row->id);
```